# Passing $stateParams when using browser navigation

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I have used ui-router in my angularjs 1.4 project. Here I am passing data using $stateParams between the router states. When I navigate using browser Forward / Backward buttons, the $stateParams that I receive is empty.

Is there any methodology to save and retrieve the $stateParams, so that I do not get empty object when using Browser Forward / Backward Button.

Answer (score 0):

You can try local storage to persist desired information such as stateParams: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp